# Existing standard(s) for passing MIDI via OSC?

Tags: standards, midi, osc

I am using OSC to feed into MIDI - so the many OSC controller apps can be used on standard MIDI kit. Just for 'proof of concept' I used this format:-

```
/midi/note_on/<note-number>
/midi/note_off/<note-number>
/midi/control_change/<control>/<value>
etc...
```

Now it seems to be doable... is there already a standard I could steal for this? If not, I am happy to define one ;)

Background: I am doing some WIFI OSC/MIDI stuff... A pyton script to act as MIDI WiFi server to receive midi/osc over IP (but really aimed at WiFi) in various flavours and piping them into the servers ALSA/MIDI system for further handling...

https://github.com/pperrin/midibridge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no OSC MIDI "standard" that would be widespread enough to be *the* standard.

You could pick the same protocol as some existing OSC implementation, but this would not be interoperable with the majority of other OSC implementations.

Comment: Thanks. I will stick with my own 'standard' then - who knows it may catch on(!). I am having to parse the incoming OSC messages anyway so can always adapt later.